# PHP errror in cos() function

Tags: php, function, internals

In an exercise I did :

```
<?php
$initial = '555';
$a = octdec($initial);
echo $a . "\n";

$b = deg2rad($a) . "\n";
echo $b;

$c = cos($b). "\n"; *(line 9)*
echo $c;
```

and it does show the correct answer, as well as an error:

```
365
6.3704517697793
0.99619469809175
PHP Notice:  A non well formed numeric value encountered in /home/ccuser/workspace/hg2pmf/index.php on line 9
```

if I change line 9 with : `$c = cos(6.3704517697793). "\n";` the message of error disappear. Why can't I use the `$` inside the `cos()` when in `deg2rad()` works perfectly?

Comment: Cannot reproduce this on my local machine (PHP v8.1.9).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that on this line...

```
$b = deg2rad($a) . "\n";
```

You are adding the new line onto the end of the calculated value.

So remove it and your value will be the number you expect...

```
$b = deg2rad($a);
```

As a help, I use

```
declare(strict_types=1);
```

and I get the error...

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: cos(): Argument #1 ($num) must be of
> type float, string given in
> which shows how it's changed the value from a number to a string.

Comment: Thanks! That's why the console was saying I put something that is not a  number.